# Salesforce Help Portal keeps refreshing all the time after logging in

Tags: help, salesforce-support

I tried to submit a case to Salesforce support from the account of our client's user. After logging in to Trailblazer.me with user's credentials I experience the following - everything is in English for the moment, then changes to Thai, after 2-3 seconds the page refreshes and everything starts from the beginning. I can't click any button and after manually pasting "Submit a Case" URL in Chrome's search bar, I experience the same. Cookies / Session Data cleared, tried to turn browser / computer off and on etc as well.

Has anyone faced a similar issue before?

Update 1: Actually it's not only the main page of Help Portal or "Submit Case" page. I can't access any resource within the `https://help.salesforce.com/` domain until I log out.

Update 2: The only workaround I have found so far is to click the X button on my browser just in a moment it appears. Then I can translate the page to English and scroll through its contents. However, it does not work for help articles - they don't load at all.

Update 3: Another workaround if you intend to submit a product case - the following URL works: `https://help.salesforce.com/s/case-submission?supportType=Support`. It's in Thai but at least the page does not refresh and you can use Google Translate.

[image: problem gif]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was changing the Country/region field for my Trailblazer Profile.

My theory is that for the user that I was logged as it was set to Denmark, and maybe because I was reaching the portal from Poland, Salesforce had some problems with processing the appropriate language version of the website (but still, why Thai?).

Changed it to "Poland", and everything started working fine:

[image]